# JSP: using expressions as values to tablib attributes

Tags: jsp, taglib

i am tring to create my own taglib, and pass a jsp variable to the taglib, as an attribute value.

<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/taglib.tld" prefix="custom"%>

```
<%String myFilter =....; %>
<custom:printAllPeople filter="<%=myFilter%>" >

</custom:printAllPeople>
```

the tld:

```
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>    
    <tag>
        <name>printAllPeople</name>
        <tagclass>jb.taglib.FilterPersonTagLib</tagclass>       
        <attribute>
            <name>filter</name>
            <required>true</required>           
        </attribute>                
        <info>print all people</info>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

and i got:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /filterTagLib.jsp (line: 23, column: 1) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute filter does not accept any expressions

how can i use expressions as attribute values?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the rtexprvalue in your TLD attribute:

```
<attribute>
   <name>filter</name>
   <required>true</required>
   <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```